# iFrame request embedded in UIWebview getting cancelled in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iframe, uiwebview

The iFrame is getting rendered in iOS 7 but in iOS 8, the iFrame request embedded in `UIWeview` fails with `error 999` (Cancel). It seems that the iFrame request is getting cancelled as the main request is still in progress (`webView.isLoading` returns TRUE). So, it shows blank space instead of iFrame in web view.

This issue is specific to iOS 8. Please provide the code snippet so that the iFrame gets rendered successfully in web view (iOS 8).

```
NSString *HTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"                   
                                           "<head> \n"
                                           "<style type=\"text/css\">\n" 
                                           "iframe { max-width: 100%%; width: auto; height: auto; }" 
                                           "img { max-width: 100%%; width: auto; height: auto; }" ....]; 
[cell.webView loadHTMLString:HTML baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://"]];
```

Then, the webView delegate functions are called in the custom cell(cell):-

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    …
 }

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
```

In iOS 8, iFrame request initiates in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` and fails in `didFailLoadWithError` with `error 999`:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x7ff6cb609580 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey
```

At that point, the `webView.isLoading` is true as the main request is still not completed. Is there any way to call the iFrame request after the main request is completed ?

Comment: Please, put your codes in your question (**properly formatted**).

Comment: @Xlander, I have put the code in proper format.

Comment: @SachinAhuja - did you manage to solve it? I'm getting the same problem (only for some of the videos some of the time)

Comment: @Boaz- Sorry, this issue is still open.

Comment: i have safari bugs that only happen on ios8 on actual devices that are similar to this. dynamic iframes will show as empty. and if hooked to desktop safari debugger will show resources still loading even though the request never went out. on the ios device ui it shows loading complete. may be related.